# AngularJS: How to prevent ng-click to target child elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a tree structure that contains a folder as parent and files as children, but the same folder can also contain another folder as a child. At the first time the only visible items are the folders that can be clicked to see their files.

My problem is that when I click on the parent folder the child folder gets expanded too and I want to only see the files of the clicked folder.

For example ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qvvdqyh2/2/)) when I click on `parent folder` I don't want the `child folder` to be also expanded until I click on it.

This is my code (the code structure must not be changed):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div class="folder-group">
    <span class="folder-title" ng-click="openFolder=!openFolder">
      <i class="fa {{openFolder ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-right'}}"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      folder parent
    </span>
    <ul ng-show="openFolder">
      <li>file1</li>
      <li>file2</li>
      <li>file3</li>
      <li>file4</li>
      <li class="children-folder">
        <span class="folder-title" ng-click="openFolder=!openFolder">
          <i class="fa {{openFolder ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-right'}}"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
          folder children
        </span>
        <ul ng-show="openFolder">
          <li>file1</li>
          <li>file2</li>
          <li>file3</li>
          <li>file4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the original template:

```
<span class="folder-title" ng-click="get_menu_items(folder); openFolder =! openFolder;">
    <i class="fa {{openFolder ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-right'}}"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    {{ folder.name }}
</span>
<ul ng-show="openFolder">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="file in folder.files">
        <label>
            <input class='file-list-item' type="checkbox" name="file_map[]" value="{{ file.id }}" ng-model="file_map[file.id]" ng-click="update_selection($event)" />
            <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
            <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li menuitem ng-repeat="folder in folder.folders" ng-model="folder"></li>
</ul>


scope.get_menu_items = function(folder) {
    folders_service.get_sub_folders(folder, false, function(folders, files) {
    }, function(err, status) {
        scope.handle_top_level_errors(err, status);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the ng-click for children folder

```
          <li class="children-folder">
            <span class="folder-title" ng-click="openFolder2=!openFolder2">
              <i class="fa {{openFolder2 ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-right'}}"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
              folder children
            </span>
            <ul ng-show="openFolder2">
              <li>file1</li>
              <li>file2</li>
              <li>file3</li>
              <li>file4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

EDIT 2:

In your folder function,

You need to add `_{{$index+1}}` along with the `openFolder` name along with the loop such the names come up as openFolder_1, openFolder_2.. . I am unable to pin point your function with the above details

This following is just for reference purpose.

`<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{openFolder}}_{{$index+1}}</li>`

results in

`openFolder_1
openFolder_2`

Comment: can't rename it because that folder has the same structure as parent (generated with `ng-repeat`)

Comment: is it possible to add {{$index+1}} with iterative loop in ng-repeat function (in controller perhaps) so the naming convention is openFolder1, openFolder2 .. so on ?

Comment: Can you share the function `get_menu_items(folder)`